# Unable to insert a row in Oracle with Java (JDBC) --> error ORA-00917: missing comma

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ora-00917

I have a problem during an insert in Oracle using Java and JDBC. The error obtained is:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00917: missing comma

The data for the insert is taken from a form like a string and is parsed to the appropiated data type and then is saved in an object called edicio. That's all OK. Then, my intention is make an insert in the DB using the data of this object.

Here is the code of the DAO, where I'm making the insert:

```
public Edicio insertarCurs(Connection con, Edicio ed) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement stm = null;
    ResultSet rst = null;

    // Insert
    StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();
    sql.append("INSERT INTO curs (id, nom, idarea, area, programa, datainici)");
    sql.append(" VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?");
    logger.info("Building insert works fine.");

    try {
        stm = con.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
        // params
        stm.setLong(1, ed.getIdEdicio());
        stm.setString(2, ed.getNomEdicio());
        stm.setLong(3, ed.getIdArea());
        stm.setString(4, ed.getArea());
        stm.setString(5, ed.getPrograma());
        // Conversion from Java Date to SQL Date
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(ed.getDataInici().getTime());
        logger.info("sqlDate before the insert is: "+ sqlDate); //0011-12-02
        stm.setDate(6, sqlDate);

                // Data and results commented
        logger.info("Id edicio: "+ ed.getIdEdicio()); //6
        logger.info("Nom edicio: "+ ed.getNomEdicio()); //test
        logger.info("Id area: "+ ed.getIdArea()); //0
        logger.info("Nom area: "+ ed.getArea()); //test
        logger.info("Programa: "+ ed.getPrograma()); //test
        logger.info("Data inici: "+ sqlDate); //2011-06-06

        // We are going to execute the insert
        int numRows = stm.executeUpdate();
        // The program never reaches this point, fails doing the executeUpdate()
                logger.info("Rows created: "+ numFiles);
                ...
```

The variable types are:

```
idEdicio = long  
nomEdicio = String  
idArea = long  
area = String  
programa = String  
dataInici = Date
```

Can someone help me? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Side note : there is no point in using a StringBuffer to concatenate static Strings. Using `String sql = "Insert into..." + " values ..."` is OK.

Comment: Maybe use that logger.info to output the sql, not just a comment.  Then copy/paste the sql into an editor like Toad and try to execute.  Many times it will show you the parsing issue, much better than banging your head looking at a bunch of string concats ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Missing `)`

```
sql.append(" VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?");
```

should be

```
sql.append(" VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

Comment: Holy s**t! Thank you very much, this "problem" was breaking my head!

Answer (score 5):

```
sql.append(" VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                                     ^--- missing parenthesis
```